# Как перенести таблицу в другую таблицу?

Tags: 1с

Пишу обработку, заполняю таблицу данными из эксель. после загрузки у меня имеется таблица значений. мне необходимо перенести эту таблицу в другой док, записать его програмно. метод с индексом и счётчиком использовать не хотелось бы, но помогите уже хоть как-нибудь это реализовать. таб1-искочительно строковый тип. таб2-всё ссылочные типы. **Задача перенести таб1 в таб2**

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ЗаписьНаСервере()
    ДокКор                              = Документы.КорректировкаРегистров.СоздатьДокумент();  
    ДокКор.Дата                         = ТекущаяДата();
    ЖПТаб                               = ДокКор.Движения.ЖурналПроводокЕПСБУ;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрока Из Объект.Таблица1 Цикл  
        Таб                             = объект.Таблица1;
        НовСтрТЧДокумента               = ЖПТаб.Добавить();
        СЧ                              = ПланыСчетов.ЕПСБУ.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.Счёт, Истина);
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.СчетКт        = СЧ;
        //НовСтрТЧДокумента.КФО         = объект.Таблица1.КФО; 
        СКПС                            = Справочники.КлассификационныеПризнакиСчетов.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.КПС, Истина);
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.КПСКт         = СКПС;
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.КоличествоКт  = Таб.Количество; 
        СНОМ                            = Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.Номенклатура, Истина);
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.СубконтоКт1   = Таб.СНОМ;
        СКЭК                            = Справочники.КОСГУ.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.КЭК, Истина);
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.КЭККт         = СКЭК;
        СЦМО                            = Справочники.ЦМО.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.ЦМО, Истина);
        НовСтрТЧДокумента.ЦМОКт         = СЦМО;

    КонецЦикла;
    ДокКор.Записать();  
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вариант по совету:

```
Процедура ЗаписьНаСервере()
    ДокКор                              = Документы.КорректировкаРегистров.СоздатьДокумент(); 
    
    Для Каждого стр из Объект.Таблица1 цикл
        НовСтрока   =   ДокКор.Движения.ЖурналПроводокЕПСБУ.Добавить();
        Для Каждого Реквизита из Объект.Таблица1 цикл
            Таб = объект.Таблица1;
        НовСтрока.СчетКт        = ПланыСчетов.ЕПСБУ.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.Счёт, Истина);  
        НовСтрока.КПСКт         = Справочники.КлассификационныеПризнакиСчетов.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.КПС, Истина); 
        НовСтрока.КоличествоКт  = Таб.Количество;   
        НовСтрока.СубконтоКт1   = Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.Номенклатура, Истина);   
        НовСтрока.КЭККт         = Справочники.КОСГУ.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.КЭК, Истина);   
        НовСтрока.ЦМОКт         = Справочники.ЦМО.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.ЦМО, Истина); 
        КонецЦикла;
    КонецЦикла;
    ДокКор.Записать();  
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом для решения любой задачи необходимо сделать две вещи:

1. Описать алгоритм решения (крупными блоками)
2. Запрограммировать каждый блок алгоритма

Общий алгоритм может выглядеть так:

```
// Создать новый документ
// Для каждой строки ИсходнойТаблицыДанных
//    Добавить строку в РезультирующуюТаблицуЗначений документа
//    Для каждого Реквизита строки ИсходнойТаблицыДанных // <- этот блок можно сделать без использования цикла (как в примере)
//        Преобразовать Реквизит к ссылочному типу
//        Записать реквизит в РезультирующуюТаблицуЗначений
```

Попробуйте самостоятельно реализовать шаг 2 по описанному алгоритму (тем более что большая часть кода уже есть в примере);
Просто сделайте код более аккуратным (у Вас полно повторных присвоений, строка в новом документе не создается, Движения вообще не понятно зачем ...)

Comment: таблица,что находится в документе-регистр,а точнее план счетов,ну т.е. этот документ делает изменения в план счетов. а движения тут...это просто ссылка на другую таблицу(таб 2),ну точнее на её местонахождения,без "движения" в коде,оно тупо не находит таблицу

Comment: Стандарной схемой работы Документа является: заполнение табличной части, формирование проводок по данным табличной части; Что касается именно документа "КорректировкаРегистров" тут видимо схема работы более сложная; Проанализируйте Табличные части этого документа, посмотрите что в них записано (на примере имеющегося в базе документа) Затем заполняйте табличную часть - аналогичным образом

Comment: я сделал аккуратнее,переписал, но всё равно оно не обнаруживает ячейку,выдаёт ошибку: 
Поле объекта не обнаружено (Счёт)

{ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаИзExcel.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(134)}: 
НовСтрока.СчетКт  = ПланыСчетов.ЕПСБУ.НайтиПоНаименованию(Таб.Счёт, Истина); 
{ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаИзExcel.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(147)}: ЗаписьНаСервере();

Comment: Если что,я предоставил исправленный код в вопросе(выше)

Comment: ну проще говоря,как я понял,я как-то не верно выделяю ячейку из исходной таблицы, от того оно не видит ячейку

Comment: Для Каждого СтрТаб из Объект.Таблица1 цикл ; // Цикл по таблице значений должен выглядеть так, обращение к колонкам строки, СтрТаб.Счет; (ё желательно не использовать)

Comment: спасибо,есть хоть какое-то продвижение. но всё равно некоторые колонки он не видит,но начало положено,спасибо

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста у меня "НовСтрока.СубконтоКт1",у неё ссылочный тип, и не на 1 вариант,а там динамический список, и он становится доступным только после выбора счёта, мне нужно дёрнуть именно тот справочник,что я указал, но при запуске(прогонке) программы, выдаёт ошибку,что не находит "НовСтрока.СубконтоКт1",как это можно решить?

Comment: Установите точку останова на строке где возникает ошибка; Запустите в режиме отладки и выполните все необходимые действия (в результате которых возникает ошибка); При передаче управления в отладчик - откройте Табло, добавьте переменную НовСтрока, затем нажмите + после чего увидите все доступные Поля(имена реквизитов) у НовСтрока